# Install sql server with component SqlPackage.exe

Tags: sql-server, cmd, command-line

Installs sql server using commands line but I miss SqlPackage.exe. It's probably in one of the Feature Parameters, but unfortunately I don't know which one.

Probably this should create that path for sql server 2017:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe

Documentation with all Feature Parameters:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver15#Feature

Comment: Try downloading and installing [sqlpackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage-download) separately. I don't think it's included with the SQL installation media.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SqlPackage.exe is not part of the SQL Server installation. It comes under SQL Server Data Tools team. You can download the Sqlpackage.exe using below link

[SQLPackage.exe Download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/release-notes-sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Below is a excerpt from SQL Server Data Tools team blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ssdt/changes-to-ssdt-and-sqlpackage-exe-installation-and-updates)

> SqlPackage.exe is a command line tool that gives many of the same
>   features used in SSDT (to publish, extract, import and export
>   databases). If you want to take advantage of the latest features such
>   as Azure Key Vault support for Always Encrypted in SqlPackage, we
>   recommend you install the DacFramework.msi which includes all the
>   Azure DLLs needed to connect and publish to Azure SQL DB.
>
> - SSDT will continue to install SqlPackage.exe in "C:\Program Files
>     (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>     14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\130" so that users running on build agents won't have scripts broken, but this will not
>     have Azure support at present.
> - SSMS now has its own copy of DacFx, so
>     updates to DacFramework.msi will not affect SSMS (and vice versa).
> - DacFramework.msi installs to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>     Server\130\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" and updates independently of SSDT /
>     SSMS.
> - We will work to get an easier installation for future updates so
>     you do not need an MSI to install SqlPackage.exe

Comment: Is there any meaning that I have version 17.9.1 of SQL Server Management and Sql Server 2017? I cant find other version then this from link.

Comment: Sql Server management tool version is different from SQL Server version. SSMS is standalone tool. You can download latest version from here: <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15>. It is currently 18.5. For SQL Server, latest version is SQL Server 2019 ie., SQL Server version 15